# Thread with Runnable using lambda

Tags: java, lambda

I have this code:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //implement
    }

});
```

My IDE(intellij) suggest to use:

```
new Thread(() -> {
    //implement
});
```

This guarantee is the same thing? I ask this because class [Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread()) has multiple constructors.

Comment: Yes it is the same `Tread` with `Runnable` as a parameter

Comment: It is the same, which you could also have found out by i.e. running the code

Comment: that is a really hippie IDE, don't trust it. old school ftw

Comment: As Runnable is a functional interface it satisfies this lambda expression.Both are same just style of coding is different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is equivalent, trust your IDE!

Regarding multiple constructors:

- you have exactly one constructor argument -> two possible constructor implementations
- is `() -> { //implement }` a `String`? - **no** -> only one possible constructor to call -> the one for `Runnable`, which you would call on your own as well.

Comment: upvoting because of clarification of hippi IDEs

Comment: Thank you. Was not very clear for me how the selection of constructor is done. I'm relatively new with lambda.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a similar thing. Both the representation would call the [`Thread(Runnable runnable)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.Runnable)) constructor.

The later code in your question

```
() -> { //implement }
```

is a ***lambda representation*** of the ***anonymous class*** in the code previous to it :

```
new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //implement
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're wondering how is that representation possible. Its because `Runnable` is a `@FunctionalInterface`.

Comment: `@FunctionalInterface` is just informative. It's not required.

Comment: @Michael I really didn't mean the annotation but the classification there. Though I hastily pasted the content, I hope that clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

It is similar, but not the exactly same thing. It behaves the same way in all the regular cases. Some methods access their stack (trace). Those might yield different results.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is the same. You can use the lambda Expression because interface Runnable has the Annotation @FunctionalInterface.

Comment: Well, it is not *required* to use the `@FunctionalInterface` annotation; the annotation is just an indication to the compiler that the targeted interface should be a functional interface.

Comment: Strictly speaking the annotation is irrelevant, the reason a lambda can be is that `Runnable` only has one method.